# React Native delay keyboard showing up on android

Tags: react-native

I'm struggling with a keyboard behavior related problem on android : )

Current behavior: `user clicks on a textinput` -> `keyboard shows up right away`

I would like to perform an action after user clicks on textinut and before keyboard shows up, e.g.
`user clicks on a textinput` -> `I perform my action` -> `keyboard awaits for my action and then shows up` (my action takes less than a second so probably we don't actually need to delay keyboard but just find a way to do my action a bit earlier)

I need something like `willFocus` event in TextInput or a way how I can delay keyboard for a sec. On iOS we have `keyboardWillShow` event but not on android : (

P.S. when I use `onFocus` textinput's event my action and keyboard shows up at the same time and it looks ugly